# T-SQL table creation in source

Tags: sql-server, create-table

I'm starting a new SQL Server Azure DB from scratch. I want to establish a strong source control so I want to be careful in how I create all my tables.

What is the best method to check if the table exists and only execute my `CREATE TABLE` statement if it does not exist yet? I'm working with passing dynamic SQL to a stored procedure that checks for the tables existence, but that is so limiting. There has to be a preferred way to do this out there. I mean I could preface every query with:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
               FROM sys.objects
               WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].j[myTable]') AND type in(N'U'))
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE myTable(....)
END
```

But that's pretty repetitive.

Answer (score 0):

More simply:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE Name = N'myTable') 
   CREATE TABLE myTable .......
```

Idea: use the *more focused* `sys.tables` catalog view, instead of the all-encompassing `sys.objects` - then you don't have to remember those rather unintuitive `type` values..... - but yes, that **is** the safest way to do this kind of code.

As of SQL Server 2016, you can also use the

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS myTable;
CREATE TABLE myTable .......
```

command (which is new - see here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2015/11/03/drop-if-exists-new-thing-in-sql-server-2016/)